# monadically iterating over a Data.Sequence

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I have a Data.Sequence which I need to iterate over. The problem is that its stateful, and the sequence may grow as a result of said iteration.

```
data Chart = Chart {
       charts :: M.Map Int (Seq.Seq RState), --map from position to list of chart states
       ...
} deriving (Show)


processChartSeq :: Int -> Int  -> State Chart ()
processChartSeq chtIndx stIndx = do s <- get
                                    let seq = fromJust $ M.lookup chtIndx (charts s)
                                        rstate = Seq.index seq  stIndx
                                    processState rstate
                                    when (stIndx < Seq.length seq) (processChartSeq chtIndx (stIndx+1))
```

So I'm doing this with explicit recursion, but it seems clunky. Furthermore, it seems like a common thing to do. What common monadic control structure did I re-invent, badly?

Comment: Are you not working inside state monad ?

Comment: If the sequence only changes by appending things, and all you ever do with the sequence is the lookup you showed, then you reinvented breadth-first search (badly). Grab a queue implementation from Hackage and enjoy.

Comment: +Satvik, yes, I'm working in the State monad. +Daniel Wagner, yes, the sequence is only changed by appending. Is there a queue implementation I should use instead of Data.Sequence? Data.Queue says its deprecated in favor of Data.Sequence

Comment: @nont `Seq` is an okay queue implementation, but you need to use it like a queue. Use `|>` to push and `viewl` to pop -- and `index` not at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the initial question, you "reinvented" the state monad within the state monad itself! You could move the stuff you're explicitly threading into your state to avoid passing it directly. On the other hand, for simple things like this, I have no problem passing things around explicitly, and often find it cleaner.

Finally, as Daniel Wagner notes, you should be pushing and popping from the top as much as possible, for the sake of efficiency.